# Set dynamic datasource from an API on user typing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

My requirement is

1). User should be able type an input
2). Need to fetch matching results for given input on each key stroke by querying a web api.
3). Results should be displayed as dropdown. And user should be able to select any item from the list of items. 
4). Need to query API with the selected item text to get the details.

To achieve the above I have taken a combo box and handling keyup and keydown events.

This is my code.

```
private void cmbSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
                {
                    isKeyDownOrKeyUp = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKeyDownOrKeyUp = false;
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.LShiftKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.RShiftKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.Shift || e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.Select || e.KeyCode == Keys.Control || e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
                    m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete = false;
                else
                    m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
        ConcurrentBag<Task> tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private IList<CancellationTokenSource> tokenSources = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();
        private void cmbSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
                {
                    isKeyDownOrKeyUp = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKeyDownOrKeyUp = false;
                }
                if (m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete)
                {

                    if (tokenSources.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var cancellationTokenSource in tokenSources)
                        {
                            if (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    var token = tokenSource.Token;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSearch.Text))
                    {
                        Task t;
                        t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InvokeApi(token), token);
                        tasks.Add(t);
                        tokenSources.Add(tokenSource);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmbSearch.DroppedDown = false;
                        cmbSearch.DataSource = null;
                        ClearControls();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void InvokeApi(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            try
            {
                var _with1 = cmbSearch;
                m_sLastSearchedFor = _with1.Text;
                this.UseWaitCursor = true;
                // Was cancellation already requested?  
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested == true)
                {
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                var search = CapturePlus.Find(m_sLastSearchedFor, "").ToList();

                //search.Insert(0, new MatchingAddress() {AddressId=string.Empty,Criteria=string.Empty,Text=string.Empty });
                // Was cancellation already requested?  
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested == true)
                {
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                this.UseWaitCursor = false;
                if (search.Count > 0)
                {
                    cmbSearch.DataSource = search;
                    cmbSearch.DisplayMember = "Text";
                    cmbSearch.ValueMember = "IdAndCrieria";
                    cmbSearch.DroppedDown = true;
                    cmbSearch.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    cmbSearch.Text = m_sLastSearchedFor;
                    cmbSearch.SelectionStart = cmbSearch.Text.Length;
                    cmbSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;

                }
                else
                {
                    cmbSearch.DroppedDown = false;
                    cmbSearch.DataSource = null;

                    cmbSearch.Text = m_sLastSearchedFor;
                    cmbSearch.SelectionStart = cmbSearch.Text.Length;

                    ClearControls();
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException can)
            {
                this.UseWaitCursor = false;
                cmbSearch.DroppedDown = false;
                cmbSearch.DataSource = null;
                cmbSearch.Text = m_sLastSearchedFor;
                cmbSearch.SelectionStart = cmbSearch.Text.Length;
                ClearControls();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.UseWaitCursor = false;
            }
        }

        private void cmbSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cmbSearch.SelectedIndex >= -1)
                {
                    if (isKeyDownOrKeyUp)
                        return; // Disable selection on KeyUp and Keydown.
                    var id = "";
                    var criteria = "";

                    var selectedValue = cmbSearch.SelectedValue;
                    if (selectedValue != null)
                    {
                        char[] separator = new char[] { '_' };
                        string[] split = selectedValue.ToString().Split(separator);
                        if (split != null && split.Length > 1)
                        {
                            id = split[0];
                            criteria = split[1];
                        }

                    }
                    if (id != null || criteria != null)
                    {
                        if (criteria == "Find")
                        {
                            _retrieved = false;


                            var findAddressWithId = CapturePlus.Find(m_sLastSearchedFor, id).ToList();
                            if (findAddressWithId.Count > 0)
                            {
                                cmbSearch.DataSource = findAddressWithId;
                                cmbSearch.DisplayMember = "Text";
                                cmbSearch.ValueMember = "IdAndCrieria";
                                cmbSearch.DroppedDown = true;
                                cmbSearch.Text = m_sLastSearchedFor;
                                cmbSearch.SelectionStart = cmbSearch.Text.Length;
                                cmbSearch.SelectedIndex = -1;
                                ClearControls();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cmbSearch.DroppedDown = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ClearControls();
                        }
                        if (criteria == "Retrieve")
                        {
                            var retriveAddress = CapturePlus.Retrieve(id).ToList();
                            try
                            {
                                if (retriveAddress.Any())
                                {
                                    _selectedAddress = retriveAddress.ToArray()[0];
                                    BindDetails(_selectedAddress);
                                    SetAddressToDisplay();
                                    _retrieved = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ClearControls();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                // Log exception.
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //cmbSearch.DataSource = null;
                            ClearControls();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    cmbSearch.DataSource = null;
                    cmbSearch.DroppedDown = false;
                    ClearControls();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Above code is not working as expected.

Main problem is

1). As I am using combobox, as user typing first item is getting selected by default.
2). As I am setting datasource to null, user's input is getting refreshed which is bit confusing.
3). Item is being selected on navigation through list using up and down arrows. When there is a selection change we are calling API to refresh the list again. Because of this user is not able to navigate though other items.

I don't think I have explained it completely and it may not make any sense to most of the users. Sorry for that.

Please suggest me if there are already some custom control which can be used to assign dynamic data source or a kind of text box which takes the input and displays the list in combo box style.

Comment: You can use `TextChanged` event instead of `KeyDown`. It's a bit unclear what you mean when say *dropdown*. Combobox has dropdown, but you do not operate with it *after* entering text. Instead of posting your solution (you call it *requirements*) to the problem, could you say what are you trying to do? Perhaps you could use autocomplete? Or you simply need 2 controls: textbox and listbox?

Answer (score 0):

I'd also consider inheriting from the combo box and overriding the events.
You could also pass in the function to perform to populate the list while you search. Then you can re-use the control in the future and it may may it easier to test.

Personally i'd probably go with Sinatr suggestion of creating your own control with a text box and a list.